# recvfrom() only gets up to 2048 bytes from UDP socket

Tags: sockets, udp

I have to call the function repeatedly to get all data, given that the len argument is set to 10240. But this results in blocking at last. How can I get all the data and safely return in a platform independent way?

BTW, I use netcat at the sender side:

> cat ocr_pi.png | nc -u server 5555

Is this issue relative to nc's behavior? I didn't find any parameter to set UDP packet size(-O is for TCP).
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP sends and receives data as messages.  In the `len` argument, you tell `recvfrom()` the max message size you can receive, and then `recvfrom()` waits until a full message arrives, regardless of its size.  UDP messages are self-contained.  Unlike TCP, a UDP message cannot be partially sent/received. It is an all-or-nothing thing.  If the size of the received message is greater than the `len` value you specify, the message is discarded and you get an error.

The only way `recvfrom()` blocks is if there is no message available to read.  If you don't want to block, use `select()` (or `pselect()` or `epoll` or other platform equivalent) to specify a timeout to wait for a message to arrive, and then call `recvfrom()` only if there is actually something to read.